# What the author meant by first test of a new high should fail and first test of new low should succeed?

Tags: stock-analysis, technical-analysis, trend-trading

[image: Trading the trends]

The author says the first test of a new high should fail. The first test of a new low should succeed. Watch for a breakout or breakdown the next time around. I did not understand what he meant by fail and succeed.

Comment: What book is that? Who is the author of that book?